# An interesting identity involving improper integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that, $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y\sqrt{1+t^2}}\cos(xt)dt=\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(1+t^2)}}dt,\quad y>0.$$

My attempt:

So far, I tried to use the change of variables, $1+z^2=\frac{y^2(1+t^2)}{x^2+y^2}$, such that, $$-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(1+z^2)}=-y\sqrt{1+t^2},$$ but I couldn't simplify the $\cos(xt)$.

Comment: What is the source of this identity?

Comment: It's related to the solution of the PDE $u_y=(\frac{y}{x}u)_x$. I showed that the general solution of that PDE is $u=xf(x^2+y^2)$, where $f$ is a continuous function. Then, I showed that $I(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y\sqrt{1+t^2}} \cos(xt)dt$ is a solution for the PDE.

Comment: So, I'm trying to write the function $I$ in the form $u=xf(x^2+y^2)$.